# Array of Integers vs Array Of Characters

Tags: c++, arrays

I am aware that an array of characters (basically a string) always terminates with the null character.

I was just wondering what does an array of integers end with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of characters does not end with a 0-terminator, *unless* it contains a data-structure having such a terminator (like a C-string), or by coincidence.

Similarly, integer arrays don't per se have any kind of terminator.

Comment: An array of characters doesn't end with a `'\0'` terminator unless someone puts it there.  In a lot of cases in the C library (and in C coding conventions in general), there is a requirement that someone have put it there, and a string literal will result in an array which has one.